# Notification when app not used for more than certain period

Tags: android

Is there a way to send a notification to the user that app has been downloaded but a certain task from the app is not yet complete even after certain period - say a month. One way is a background service which should come alive every month in this case, check the app state (in sharedprefs) and then send a notification. Is there some other easier way in Android without writing custom service.

Comment: do you mean like screensaver activation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wake up your app after some amount of time (in your example a month) you're going to have to set an alarm. You can use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that. If all you're going to do is check SharedPreferences, you can do that in a broadcast receiver. You can send your notification there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. Schedule an alarm using the `AlarmManager` to go off a month from today. That alarm can trigger some code inside of a `Receiver` or otherwise to check whether the said event has occured. If it hasn't, you can then show a `Dialog` or whatever.